# How to remove tags?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

There are a few tags that have no questions. I think these were previously attached to questions which have been re-tagged. For example, I changed timeseries to time-series on one question. Someone else has retagged baysian as bayesian. But the old tags, now without questions, remain on the list and will pop-up as suggestions on future questions. Is there a way of completely removing these tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a daily "janitor" task which cleans up incorrect and orphaned tags.

This is due to the denormalizations we use for performance, etc. It is possible for things to be slightly out of sync.

Comment: During the beta phase, when things like tags are more likely to be in flux, would it be possible to run the "janitor" task more frequently (e.g., every couple of hours instead of daily)?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess- but I have noticed delayed reactions to changes several times today.  I'll bet Stack Exchange is trying to be efficient by only examining global tag usage and adjusting every half hour or hour or something similar.

The test would be to see if these tags disappear after some time elapses.