# Can/should we streamline the tags on the main site?

Tags: discussion

I think it may be desirable to streamline the tags on the main site as much as possible before the site goes public. For example, there are tags such as 'data', 'dataset' etc which causes confusion and more work later on. I started doing some re-tagging but then stopped as I felt that I should find out what others have to say about this idea.

Reactions / thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest waiting 3 or 4 days. This will give us some better statistics on which tags are naturally used. After that there is still enough time to fix things before the public beta starts.

Also, probably some users will than have access to the moderation tools, which (I think) contain some easy things to do retagging.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen:

- obvious tag errors (e.g., `baysian` instead of `bayesian`),
- where there is already a tag pattern (e.g., `distributions` instead of `distribution`; at the point I changed it, I think there were 6 `distributions` and only the 1 `distribution`), or
- where there is another tag that would be appropriate (e.g., `fundamentals`),

I've changed or added the appropriate tag.  So obviously my vote in those areas is to streamline.  Anything beyond those three scenarios, I'd be hesitant to do without running it by the community.

Along those lines, if you do streamline/clean-up tags, be warned that there may be almost a daylong timelag before the daily "janitor" cleans up the [incorrect or orphaned tags](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-to-remove-tags).

As for your [`data`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) versus [`dataset`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset) example, I'd suggest you start a specific meta question.  Personally, I'm on the line and would wait to see what emerges over the next day or so.